# Magento 2 decrease coupon usage

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2

I'm trying to decrease coupon usage, but it isn't applying.
I created a coupon with a count of usage = 1, then I use the coupon to reach the limit. After that, I'm trying to set the usage value from 1 to 0 in salesrule_coupon and salesrule_coupon_usage database table - everything is ok, except for trying to use this coupon again, it says "The promo code 12345 is not valid." How can I drop the value and apply my coupon code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the appropriate db tables.
If you have a case where you need to cancel a coupon - you have to use the following database tables:

- salesrule
- salesrule_coupon
- salesrule_coupon_usage
- salesrule_customer

and their field times_used, just decrease the number of used and try to apply coupon again. Voila!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

salesrule_customer and salesrule_coupon_usage has the times_used specific to a customer